# hook_onload() replacement

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to add JS functions to the body tag's onload and onunload attributes with a custom module. The only hook I found was hook_onload() from Drupal 4.7, but this method has been deprecated. What is the Drupal 7 way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use PHP hooks to execute Javascript. You would put the Javascript you want to execute into a .js file, and then use PHP to just attach that file to any page where it is needed, for example, using [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

For example if you wanted to attach it to every page with a certain type of form you would put `drupal_add_js()` inside of a `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter)`.

If you want it on every page all the time, you can add it to your module's .info file like so:

`scripts[] 'path/to/js/foo.js`

Comment: Shouldn't `files[]` be `scripts[]`?

Comment: Yep it should be `scripts`. Also, the path is relative to the module root file, and no slash prefix. `scripts[] = js/myjs.js`.

Comment: Not to pile it on but you should also use the `#attached` property in a render array (like a form array), rather than `drupal_add_js()`.

Comment: `#attached` is generally preferred, it's true. But I chose `drupal_add_js()` for two reasons: 1. It doesn't require prior knowledge of form API to use, and 2. there are rare cases where `#attached` can't be used and I don't know if the OP's case is one of those. I have fixed the other mistakes.

Comment: So if I need specific functions to run onload and onunload, I would need to write those in an external script using document.ready and document.unload (deprecated in jQuery 1.8, but don't know a better way), and then add that JS to my .info file and that would solve my problem?

Comment: Well it depends on what your problem is, but that's how you attach a script. You can also write javascript directly into the templates but that is less modular and flexible and generally not recommended.

Comment: This is working correctly, but it appears to only be including on JS file. My assumption would be that you can add multiple scripts[] = '' to the .info file to attach additional scripts, but that doesn't seem to be working. (As an aside, it's scripts[] = not scripts[]:. At least that's the only way it'll work for me)

Comment: Actually, this is working now with two scripts. I just had them in the wrong order. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the rogue colon. Glad it helped you!